# double summation with adding and removing bar X

Tags: statistics, summation, variance, means, descriptive-statistics

I need help with this please:
we have from other question (question 1)
$$Sxx=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar X)^2=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i²-n\bar  X=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i(x_i-\bar X)$$
And we have to transform this:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n (x_i-x_j)^2$$ with the equation Sxx from earlier
(express this in term of Sxx)

the hint was to add $$\bar X-\bar X $$ making it:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n (x_i+\bar X-\bar X-x_j)^2$$

but i still cant find result

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hi, ty for reply .

Comment: "we have to transform this" to what? Can yo please clarify your question?

Comment: is it clearer? (sorry i am french speaker)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to use the hint, but:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n (x_i-x_j)^2
= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n (x_i^2 -2x_ix_j + x_j^2)
=
2n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n x_i x_j
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n x_ix_j = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2 = n^2 \bar X^2
$$
Thus:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n (x_i-x_j)^2 = 2n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - n\bar X^2\right) = 2n S_{xx}
$$

Comment: @RobPratt: I am confused -- where does $a^2$ come from?

Comment: Thank you @RobPratt. Edited.

Comment: man thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

Using the hint:
$$(x_i-x_j)^2=[(x_i-\bar X)-(x_j-\bar X)]^2=(x_i-\bar X)^2 -2(x_i-\bar X)(x_j-\bar X) + (x_j-\bar X)^2
$$
Summing over $i$ and $j$, the first term on the right gives
$$\sum_i\sum_j(x_i-\bar X)^2 = \sum_j\left(\sum_i(x_i-\bar X)^2\right)=\sum _j S_{xx}=nS_{xx}$$
and similarly the third term on the right gives
$$\sum_i\sum_j (x_j-\bar X)^2=nS_{xx}.$$
Now argue that the middle term sums to zero:
$$-2\sum_i\sum_j (x_i-\bar X)(x_j-\bar X)=0$$

Comment: life saver, tyy so much